# Django API not uploading large json data from Android OkkHttp Client

Tags: django, api, post, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a large json data from android retrofit client to django rest api view.

**For example(Json Data):**

```
{'post_data': [{'x':'asdkdadlf fdsfsd','y':'This is a paragraph........ Ending paragraph', 'created_on':'2018-22-08'},
           {'x':'asdkdadlf fdsfsd','y':'This is a paragraph........ Ending paragraph', 'created_on':'2018-22-08'},
           {'x':'asdkdadlf fdsfsd','y':'This is a paragraph........ Ending paragraph', 'created_on':'2018-22-08'},

....

           {'x':'asdkdadlf fdsfsd','y':'This is a paragraph........ Ending paragraph', 'created_on':'2018-22-08'},
           {'x':'asdkdadlf fdsfsd','y':'This is a paragraph........ Ending paragraph', 'created_on':'2018-22-08'},
]}`
```

**API Response output:**

```
08-22 13:21:12.964 15628-16104/com.mml.wapp D/Abhay: Group type: 1 group name: REAL ESTATE PROPERTYfrom:‪+234 818 230 9054‬
08-22 13:21:12.995 15628-16104/com.mml.wapp D/Abhay: Total messages in db before adding current message: 100
08-22 13:21:13.062 15628-16104/com.mml.wapp D/deleteMessage: Deleted all messages
08-22 13:21:13.200 15628-16109/com.mml.wapp D/OkHttp: --> POST https://api.multiplymyleads.com/api/upload_whatsapp_msgs/ http/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
08-22 13:21:13.204 15628-16109/com.mml.wapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 73304
08-22 13:21:13.211 15628-16109/com.mml.wapp D/OkHttp: postdata=%7B%22%E2%80%AA%2B234%20818%20230%209054%E2%80%AC%22%3A%5B%7B%22group_type%22%3A%221%22%2C%22time%22%3A%222018-08-

 ... followed by a lot more of that
```

As far as I understand, data in above response seems huge, may be that's why its getting timeout error? As its not able to upload all data in one API call in given timeout time in server side.

**What can we do to resolve above issue ?**

1. I have checked API returning success response if reduce the json post_data size.
2. I am using retrofit 2.0 client in android side for API call.

Comment: How about simply splitting this json payload and posting it in separate requests?

Comment: There will be gonna a lot of API hit from multiple android client

Comment: Removed the huge amount of *useless* data dumped. The point is to create a [mcve] and it is *enough* to give a bit of example. You absolutely should **not** have thousands of lines/bytes in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research I solved it from android side using below spinet of code.

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);;
```

Which increases timeout for response.